# Ignore white space characters in the sprintf* functions

Tags: c++, printf

I'd like to output some text using the `sprintf_s` function. Here is the code:

```
sprintf_s(g_msgbuf, "\n\
            Active Weapon PID: %d\n\
            HitMode: %s\n\
            Armor DT: %d\n\
            Armor DR: %d\n", 
            ActiveWeaponPID, 
            HitModeStr.c_str(), 
            cur_dmg_thresh, 
            cur_dmg_resist
        );
```

As one can see for the readability reasons I've put all the parameters in separate lines. The problem is that I'm getting extra unwanted white space characters (tabs) generated in-between the format string parameter:

```
Active Weapon PID: 8
            HitMode: single
            Armor DT: 4
            Armor DR: 30
```

Is there a way/parameter/option for the sprintf's functions (`sprintf_s` specifically) to ignore that redundant tabs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the fact that separate strings  will be concatenated no matter what the whitespace/new lines are between - `"one" "two" "three"` is equivalent to `"onetwothree"`

```
sprintf_s(g_msgbuf, "\n"
            "Active Weapon PID: %d\n"
            "HitMode: %s\n"
            "Armor DT: %d\n"
            "Armor DR: %d\n", 
            ActiveWeaponPID, 
            HitModeStr.c_str(), 
            cur_dmg_thresh, 
            cur_dmg_resist
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using C++'s stringstream.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::stringstream g_msgbuf;

int main()
{
    int ActiveWeaponPID{ 4 };
    std::string HitMode{ "none" };
    int cur_dmg_thresh{ 3 };
    int cur_dmg_resist{ 5 };

    g_msgbuf 
        << "Active Waepon PID: " << ActiveWeaponPID << "\n"
        << "HitMode: " << HitMode << "\n"
        << "Armor DT: " << cur_dmg_thresh << "\n"
        << "Armor DR: " << cur_dmg_resist << "\n";

    std::cout << g_msgbuf.str();
};
```

Comment: @P Kramer "You indeed didn't need the extra '\' after '\n'" - I'm afraid You're wrong here. When I remove the '\' at the end of each line I get an error (unless I use the solution proposed by Mike above). Second - "printf, sprintf are no longer considered "safe"" - yes i know so I'm using the `sprintf_s` as You can see:-)

Comment: Okay me bad on the "\" part then ;)
Yes sprintf_s is already much better, I'm just not that used to seeing any of the print functions anymore. It was not my intention to tell you you were wrong, just wanted to show you an alternative (and I like << since you can overload it for your own types so its more flexible). I'll update the comment on '\' in the answer.